# Как создать экземпляр структуры?

Tags: c#

У меня есть структура и интерфейс, подскажите как я могу создать экземпляр этой структуры.

```
public struct Card
{
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public decimal FeeAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public interface IBank
{
  IEnumerable<Card> ChargedFees();
}

public class Bank : IBank
{
   public IEnumerable<Bank> ChargedFees()
   {
      *****
   }
}
```

Comment: Card card = new Card();
И у вас метод  интерфейса  возвращает   IEnumerable<Card>. a не IEnumerable<Bank>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта:

1. `Card val;`
   и далее можете присваивать значения полям
2. Через оператор `new`. В этом случае все будет инициализированно значениями по умолчанию.

Comment: в обоих случаях будет инициализировано значениями по умолчанию же

Comment: @Grundy, вроде, в первом случае мы не сможем присваивать значения и будет ругнать, что переменную нужно инициализировать? Нет?

Comment: Хм, [действительно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7767669/2881286). Почему-то казалось что можно было.

Comment: @Grundy так то, вроде, CLR инициализирует поля в первом случае, если верить дебаггеру, но компилятор запрещает с ними работать до реального присвоения. Видать сделано для единообразия со стандартными значимыми типами.